# Gulp with live-reload

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I have a website that I've built with Node. I can successfully start and run the site by running `node server.js` from the command-line. I then access the site by visiting "http://localhost:3000" in my browser. I'm now trying to improve some of the build process surrounding the site. To do that, I'm relying on Gulp.

I want to automatically reload the webpage when a change is made to the HTML or CSS files. I stumbled upon the gulp-livereload plugin. I have installed it as described in the docs. However, when I visit "http://localhost:35729/" in the browser, I just see the following:

```
{
  minilr: "Welcome",
  version: "0.1.8"
}
```

My gulp task is configured like this:

```
gulp.task('launch',  function() {
    var toWatch = [
        'src/**/*.html',
        'src/**/*.css'
    ];

    livereload.listen();
    gulp.watch(toWatch, function() {
        console.log('reloading...');
        livereload();
    })
}
```

I do not see my home page like I do when I visit "http://localhost:3000" after running `node server.js`. What am I missing?

Comment: Livereload requires a plugin to work, another option is browsersync and it has other cool features like synchronization between several devices.  If you want I can help you with a gulp task that uses it.

Answer (score 5):

Live reload is a protocol to send notifications to the browser to do a reload.  But you need a browser plugin to listen and do the reload, although it is possible to forgo the plugin using a script tag.

The gulp-livereload plugin only concerns itself with the implementation of the livereload server, you still need to serve the files via a http server from gulp.

You can use a gulp module that does both [gulp-connect](https://github.com/avevlad/gulp-connect).

However unless you are tied to livereload for some reason, I suggest using browserync. [Browsersync](https://www.browsersync.io/) is a nice alternative to livereload that aditionally adds
the capacity of syncing your view between browsers. Since it injects a script tag into your html and listens on a socket you don't need any plugins to make it work. It works even on Mobile devices.

A gulp task to use browsersync might look like this.  Don't forget to add browsersync to your
**package.json** file

```
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('serve',  [] , function( cb ){

    browserSync.init({
        open:  true ,
        server: {
            baseDir: "src"
        }
    });

    gulp.watch([
      'src/**/*' ,
    ] , ['serve:reload'] );

});

gulp.task('serve:reload' , []  , function(){
  browserSync.reload();
});
```

Comment: There is a way to do it without the browser plugin. It's mentioned here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/livereload#method-2-add-code-to-page. However, I can't seem to get the app to start via live reload.

Comment: I'm assuming you are using gulp-livereload, on closer inspection it is using tyny-lr npm module. This module only concern itself with the livereload server but you still need to have a web server to serve the files.  There a several other gulp modules that do both ( serve and livereload ) on example is https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-connect. However I still find browsersync superior to livereload and recommend you use it instead.

Comment: I've written a server via express. The server is placed in a file called server.js. For that reason, I do  not believe I need gulp-connect. Yet, I'm not sure what I should be using.

Comment: Good, so using your express app port livereload doesn't work? Did you check the dev console to make sure the script file is being correctly loaded into the page?

Comment: In the terminal window, I see ```Server started http://localhost:8080 LiveReload started on port 35729" ``` When I visit "http://localhost:3000/", I get a ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. When I visit "http://localhost:8080/" I see a directory listing with the files and folders in my code structure. When I visit "http://localhost:35729/", I see ```
{"tinylr":"Welcome","version":"0.2.1"}``` Its like server.js is not getting ran/started. Yet, I don't know why. What would cause that?

Answer (score 3):

Why are you visiting 'http://localhost:35729/' ? If this is port where livereload is listening then it won't show your site, because as you said your site is available from 'http://localhost:3000'.

I assume that you have correctly configure gulp. By it I mean that livereload is listening, and you watch changes in your files and in pipes you have '.pipe(livereload()'.

1. You have to install https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/livereload/jnihajbhpnppcggbcgedagnkighmdlei
2. you have to run your app 'http://localhost:3000' in chrome browser.
3. you will have in browser plugin bar new icon (this is icon of this plugin)
4. you have to click this icon to run this plugin
5. finish

Now when you change something in files, gulp watcher will notice this, do some work, and inform chrome plugin that there are changes, This plugin will refresh your project page.

Comment: The reason I'm visiting http://localhost:35729 is because that is the default port for livereload (https://www.npmjs.com/package/livereload). I was trying to implement this so that I did *not* have to install the browser plugin. I wanted to ensure this works in Firefox and Safari as well.

Comment: I also added my gulp task. Its still not working. I'm not sure why.

Comment: I don't have experience in manual handling livereload, sorry. But it will not just start to working if you open livereload port in browser. If you need manually implement this probably your app should to listen to this port and in some condition trigger reloading. Livereloading it only for your developing purposes not for your clients, therefore it don't have to be crossbrowser. Check this page : http://livereload.com/extensions/ there are more browser supported